# How to change VS2010 Add Reference box filter?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm getting used to the new IDE (it's vc# express), but the first contact is somewhat confusing. When I open the Add Reference dialog and switch to the .NET tab, a label above the assembly list states: "Filtered to:.NET Framework 4". And it's true - I can reference .NET 4.0 assemblies only plus things like XNA 3.1. However I can't see older assemblies i.e. Managed DirectX libs, which are obviously installed on my computer as there was no trouble with adding a ref to them in vc#08.

What is this? How to change the filter? The label is read-only. These sound like dull guy's questions, but I'm out of luck in finding an answer and there is no intuitive solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've created a tool that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image]

Regards

s

Comment: It was some time until I got full version of VS2010 (the edition in question was Express). Your extension works fine, but a case-insensitive search would be useful, at least optionally.

Comment: @Fly_Trap - Cheers...  @rook - Soon will be releasded second version of this sexy extension with case-insensitive search

Answer (score 17):

Change your new application to target the .NET Framework 4 and **not** .NET Framework 4 ***Client***

"When you create a new application, some projects target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile by default."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

"If you are targeting the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot reference an assembly that is not in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Instead you must target the .NET Framework 4. "

Comment: Thanks for info. However, my application was targeting .NET Framework 4 already. Then I tried to change the target to Client Profile and back to full framework with hope it'll repair a possible deadlock. No effect. While .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is set, the label on Add Reference window says "Filtered to:.NET Framework 4 Client Profile".

Changing framework target to v3.5 results in displaying some additional assemblies, e.g. WindowsForms 2.0, but MDX is still not there. It makes sense, because it's built for an earlier framework version. In my case the filter is nothing but a spoiler.

Answer (score 7):

> How to change the filter?

Very simple - you must change the Target .NET Framework for your project, as whole. It's not pain :) just RMB on project name in Solution Explorer->Properties->Application tab->Target Framework(combobox). Select what you want. Change combobox == change filter in Add Reference dialog. ;)

Comment: Note: "RMB" = "Right Mouse Button" or "right-click." Took me a moment to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar problem until I noticed that the older .NET assemblies were actually in the list, there's just some really strange sorting going on.  If you sort by assembly name, you should see them in the proper order.

Comment: I read about the sorting problem, so I kept it in mind. However to be sure, I followed your advice, but it only confirms the problem. Some assemblies are not there!

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me! Sad, they tried to improve the dialog window bu actually made it worse. The sorting, for instance, does not work  before the asynchronous load has completed. You click on grid headers and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to go into your project’s Properties page and change the Target Framework from 4.0 to your desired Framework.  You will then need to reload you application.  Now your Reference should be there.  Once you have added the Reference you want, change back to 4.0 and again reload.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If, for instance, your project is Framework 4 and you want to reference say Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller (which is not in the filtered list of the .NET tab), then go to the Browse tab and enter the path to the reference item e.g. C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

Comment: This requires the user know where the library is located to browse too.